# TextBox with numbers only in the format ####.##

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, regex, textbox

I figured out how to type in only numbers in a text box, using this function

```
  function isNumberKey(evt) {
      var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
      if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31
        && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
          return false;

      return true;
  }
```

but I only want it to follow ####.## in that particular syntax, that way it doesn't cause an error in oracle when it gets submitted.

I'm not good with regular expressions, and was wondering if someone could point me the direction or help me out.

Comment: Don't forget to use either 'Regex' or an 'Automata' to check the format on the server sider. Don't trust just on JS to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the AjaxControlToolkit to do it pretty easily:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx

Use the FilteredTextBox to limit characters, then a MaskedEdit to enforce your format.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match the format you provided.

```
var matches = str.match(^\d{4}\.\d{2})
if (matches) //matches will be no if no matching values are returned.
{
    //You have valid input
}
```

Comment: is there a way to apply this regex in javascript? i know how to check in the server side but not the client side

Comment: You can apply it by doing str.match(^\d{4}\.\d{2}) on the string you are checking in the textbox. See this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

Comment: I tried making this function, but it doesnt seem to like it.  it seems to be highlighting the ^\ and the \'s. I'm not sure if hte regex format is different in javsascript

Answer (score 0):

Use [MaskedEdit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx) to enforce your pattern. its very easy.

```
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender
    TargetControlID="TextBox2" 
    Mask="####.##"
    MessageValidatorTip="true" 
    OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" 
    OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError"
    MaskType="Number" 
    InputDirection="RightToLeft" 
    AcceptNegative="Left" 
    DisplayMoney="Left"
    ErrorTooltipEnabled="True"/>
```